# url in window.open is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

**UPDATED**

I have a page where i upload an image to crop which opens a window with the required functionality, it works absolutely fine as per below given script, but it doesn't work with IE

```
<script>
window.open('http://mymachine/mysite/crop.php?bgimagecode1=1281439586.jpg&x=728&y=364&id=30&bannersize=1x2&osCsid=','mywindow','fullscreen=yes,scrollbars=yes');
</script>
```

please help

Comment: Can you paste the actual string output instead of the PHP code? Also, are you using any VBScript on the page?

Comment: The output should be a popup window which is displayed in FF but not in IE.. it doesnt have any specific output

Comment: @OM: I meant the string output passed as the first argument to *window.open()*

Comment: Shouldn't ."& id=". be actually ."&id=".

Comment: @OM: do you receive any error messages in IE?  Have you tried using the developer tools to see if it picks up any issues?

Comment: No its not displaying any issue

Comment: What version of IE. You are talking about all of them or just 6,7,8,9? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have IE set to block popups? You have to whiteflag the domain or it won't open. I would check your preferences.

Comment: I checked it i have set them as "allowed"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP to generate this string, you should be using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to make sure the URL's querystring is valid.

Answer (score -1):

Don't set the second parameter. It doesn't work in IE... just leave it empty.

```
window.open('". HTTP_SERVER . "/crop.php?bgimagecode1=".$realname."&x=".$w."&y=".$h."& id=".$_POST['categoryId']."&bannersize=".$_POST['size']."&osCsid=".$_POST['sid']."','','fullscreen=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

More info in [a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument)...

Comment: -ve i need it. i cant do that

Comment: @Andy E: I had the some problem and by leaving the second parameter empty (the title of the window) it solved my problem.

Comment: @thomas: That can happen if the name has spaces or other invalid characters in it.  A valid name will work just fine.

Comment: @thomasvdb The second parameter is the string that just names the new window. Such string can be used to be the target of links and forms when the target attribute of an <a> element or of a <form> is specified. This string parameter should not contain any blank space. strWindowName does not specify the title of the new window. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.open]