# Error with window.open - JavaScript and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

```
function printThis(patientId) {
    window.open("print.aspx?ID=" + patientId, "Site", "menubar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=900");
}
```

works fine with firefox and chrome but not with IE (9.0 at least) - "invalid argument", what's the issue and what's the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: printThis? Are you doing some popup based printer friendly version instead of using a print media stylesheet?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/710756/97658

Comment: @David - yes, print media CSS is not applicable in this case.

Comment: Is "Site" your actual 2nd parameter? or have you simplified the code sample. In IE, if you have spaces or a dash in the name (2nd parameter) it will throw an `invalid argument` error.

Answer (score 1):

Window.open must be called from an onClick event. Otherwise Mr popup blocker will eat your window.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (well replacing your aspx with a valid url). Are you sure the pop-up blocker is not eating your window.open ?