# Why my window.open(...) is not working in IE 7?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a index.html page, which contains a button`id="my-btn"`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My INDEX PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><input type="button" id="my-btn" value="OPEN NEW WINDOW"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/my.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***js/my.js*** handles button click event, when `my-btn` button is clicked, a new browser window will be popped up with a new page(**test.html**)

**my.js:**

```
$('#my-btn').click(function(){  
  window.open('test.html', 'testwindow');
});
```

The new page(***test.html***) opened in new browser window:

**test.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-name"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Every thing is **working fine in FireFox**, but I got problem in IE 7.

In IE 7, when `my-btn` is clicked, the new window is **not** popped up, instead, I got error message "**Invalid argument**" which is point to my js code `window.open('test.html', 'testwindow');`, how to make it working in IE then???

Comment: Maybe there's a popup blocker enabled in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.open('test.html','');` (according to this question/answer [ie8 var w= window.open() - "Message: Invalid argument."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument))

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).. The problem lies with you second argument..