# JavaScript Onclick window.open will not work properly in IE

Tags: javascript

I hope my question is one that is simple to answer, but unfortunately I don't have a great knowledge of javascript. I've spend a good portion of the day Googling the issue and trying various workarounds, but nothing has worked adequately thus far.

I am running a very simple piece of JavaScript so that when an image is clicked a separate window opens. This will work in every other browser (including mobile) except for IE. Following is what I've included in my head tag -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function open_win() {
 window.open("music/player/song-of-my-soul.html", "_blank, _top", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=mo, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, toolbar=no, copyhistory=yes, width=240, height=400,");
 }
</script>
```

I have then created a div with a background image and hover image, that when clicked should open the above page. Following is the line I have placed within the div -

a href="#" alt="Listen to Samples" title="Listen to Samples" class="play-link" onclick="open_win()">

This works fine in every other browser, but will not work in IE. I have tried several ways to reference the JavaScript in the head, but none of them will work.

The page that I'm testing this on can be seen at the following - http://www.christlikemusic.com/song-of-my-soul.php#  The 'Play' button in the center towards the bottom is the image that I have linked.

If anyone would have any ideas on how I might fix this I would be most grateful !

David

Comment: In IE there are some javascript errors in the page, did you check what are they?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument

Answer (score 6):

You have a trailing comma in the windows options list:

```
 [snip] ... copyhistory=yes, width=240, height=400,");
                                                  ^--- here
```

IE is notoriously stubborn about trailing commas, and will regularly barf all over itself if it comes within a few miles of one.

Comment: And JavaScript is notoriously unforgiving about syntax ;)

Comment: @ Marc B 

Thanks so much for pointing that out. I'm still getting used to JS . .

Answer (score 2):

The window name can not have space.

So you need to change `"_blank, _top"` to something else.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I was able to change it and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the window.open with the void function:

**EDIT**: You also had a trailing comma after the `height` specification.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function open_win() { 
        void(window.open("music/player/song-of-my-soul.html", "_blank, _top", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=mo, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, toolbar=no, copyhistory=yes, width=240, height=400")); 
    } 
</script>
```

Here's a method that I created for opening child windows. You can use this if you'd like:

```
openChildWindowWithDimensions = function(url, width, height, showMenu, canResize, showScrollbars) {
    var childWindow = window.open(url, "", "\"width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",menubar=" + (showMenu ? "1" : "0") + ",scrollbars=" + (showScrollbars ? "1" : "0") + ",resizable=" + (canResize ? "1" : "0") + "\"");
    if (childWindow){
        childWindow.resizeTo(width, height); //IE9 bug
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out James. Appreciate you sharing your method too. I was able to sort it out using one of the other suggestions though. 
Thanks again . .

Comment: @James Johnson: using the void function cured my problem (I had used windows.open in a sitemapnode url attribute.  Worked fine in all browsers except IE.  With void, it works fine in all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second argument. Try

```
window.open("music/player/song-of-my-soul.html", "_blank", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=mo, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, toolbar=no, copyhistory=yes, width=240, height=400");
```

The second parameter is the name of the window to be opened. It has to be a valid name, in your case you have passed it as `_blank, _top` which is not a valid name. It can be `_blank`.

You can find more valid values [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) and IE definitions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you are using a new IE version like IE8/IE9 then you can run the command using the developer tool which comes with IE and find that the `window.open` is throwing an `invalid argument` error.

Comment: Thanks for that Arun, it was exactly the problem. Your suggestion worked perfectly ! Hugely appreciate the help =)