# window.open not working in internet explorer despite being triggered by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ie8 var w= window.open() - “Message: Invalid argument.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument)

check this page out: http://jsfiddle.net/S7Crc/

notice that clicking on click me opens a window properly in firefox but not in internet explorer despite the fact that the window.open is triggered by the user...

how do I get Internet Explorer to properly execute window.open and have it behave the same with Firefox? (note that I need to set the width and height of the window so a simple target _blank or target _new are NOT viable alternatives)

Comment: If you check your javascript console, you'd see you're getting an "invalid argument" error.

Comment: [jquery popup window](http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the 2nd parameter for `open()`, the hyphen is not allowed there in IE

Use only characters[a-zA-Z], digits  and the underscore for the 2nd argument