# Window.open working in all the browser except IE, when I hit the link, getting an error Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

It's working in all the browsers except `IE`, when I hit the link, getting an error:

> Invalid argument

HTML File...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link">Open new window</a>
```

JS File...

```
$("link").observe("click", function () {
    window.open(location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/" + "location.html", "Help desk", "width=643,height=600,resizable=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,left=200");
});
```

Why is it not working in IE?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE only supports [a limited subset of names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462500/135978) for the window and "Help Desk" is not one of them.  Changing that argument to `"_blank"` will fix your issue.