# window.open is throwing invalid argument error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open

I have IE version 11.0.9600.17358

```
window.open('editProperties.php?fileid=661BEAB9735A615D65B3FCF676A2F83F', 'editProperties', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=570,height=580,left=490,top=362');
```

throws invalid argument error. I tried creating a test.html and calling it just by name:

```
window.open('test.html')
```

it does not work, throws the same error. Only time I was able to use it was as:

```
window.open('', 'editProperties','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=570,height=580,left=490,top=362')
```

or

```
window.open('about:blank')
```

As soon as I pass a url as the first argument, it throws the error. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to pass in the full URL, starting with http(s).

Comment: For more info see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Comment: @Halcyon I've already tried passing window.open('https://internal.website.com/editProperties.php?fileid=661BEAB9735A615D65B3FCF676A2F83F', '','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=570,height=580,left=490,top=362');

Comment: @Huangism I've already read that. I've passed full url, I've made sure the name argument does not have any space or weird characters.

Comment: @PersyJack can you reproduce this on a http://jsfiddle.net ? I tried your script and it works fine on my IE 11 VM. Are you 100% sure the error is coming from window open?

Comment: The code works as it is, the error has to be thrown from somewhere else, or there's something you are not showing us.

Comment: You specifically mention IE - does it work correctly in other browsers?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes it does. Chrome and firefox work as expected. For the sake of the argument, I've tried calling window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426401/window-open-is-throwing-invalid-argument-error-in-ie', '', 'width=500px') from the console and it work. So I guess something wrong with the server settings, I'm not sure

Comment: Your fist line runs for me http://jsfiddle.net/g9jv1fyx/

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'll investigate the server side. Maybe because it's https

Comment: Just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument) - potentially a duplicate?  Looks like the window name is the issue in IE.

Comment: @JamesThorpe `editProperties` is a valid window name.

Comment: @Teemu That's correct, it should open it without passing the full path. The example I gave to JamesThorpe works (opening this page in a popup). So I know it's not internet explorer's fault. However, it doesn't produce any error on other browsers, they just work.

Comment: @Teemu Yeah - just wanted to highlight it in case this wasn't a direct copy/paste of the code with the issue, and the original code may have had some invalid (as far as IE is concerned) characters in the name

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, that's possible (or in the URL as well), but even `about:blank` is not working ...

Comment: @Teemu I read it that `about:blank` and empty URL was working?

Comment: Guys it was something to do with windows authentication or session, I'm not really sure but opening another tab fixed the issue. I have no clue.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yeah, my bad. Anyway, looks like OP has a clue now, it seems to be something, which is not posted.

Comment: @Teemu Yep.  Wierd error to throw if it's an authentication issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow, I've opened another tab, which asked me my credentials again, after entering it, the same exact link just worked. It seems like the session timeout or something but still showed me the page between loads. If anyone encounters this error and none of the comments above work, try opening a new tab!!
Thank you all for trying to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the name parameter, as for example:

```
window.open('/somefile.html', '', 'width=300');
```

Maybe [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument) you shall find more details.